# Play: where to place a bash script to be distributed

Tags: playframework

I would like my Play app to call a bash script that I'd distribute with the application. But I don't know where to place the script in the project structure:

- It must be in `/dist` because otherwise it won't be distributed.
- I cannot call the script with `"bash dist/scripts/myscript.sh".!!`, because when deployed, there is no more `dist` directory (`scripts` is at the root).
- I cannot call the script with `"bash scripts/myscript.sh".!!`, because maybe it works when deployed, but I cannot test it in development.

I thought I could use a soft link in development, but is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add scripts to the distribution package:

1. Add to the project a folder **scripts**
2. Add on top of the build.sbt import to NativePackagerHelper:

   ```
   import NativePackagerHelper._
   ```
3. Add to the build.sbt mapping to a new directory:

   ```
   mappings in Universal ++= directory("scripts")
   ```
4. Build the distribution package with ***activator dist***

You can find more details on [my blog](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/adding-distribution-folder-play-application.html)